# Creating same unique constraint with different names

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sql-standard

In MySQL 5.7

1. `alter table mydb.roles add constraint uk1 unique (role_name);`
2. `alter table mydb.roles add constraint uk2 unique (role_name);`

The 2<sup>nd</sup> `alter` command threw me a warning stating:

> Duplicate index 'uk2' defined on the table 'world_x.roles'. This is
>   deprecated and will be disallowed in a future release.

When I tried the same in Postgres(10.x), it didn't warn me.

So, what would the SQL standard be in this scenario?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I guess that the SQL standard doesn't say much about duplicate constraints. I'm almost certain that it says nothing about duplicate indexes, since indexes are considered a physical implementation, and not part of the standard.

Comment: your error message isn't possible as you don't mention uk3 in that code anywhere.

Comment: @EvanCarroll edited/correct the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be result very confusing mixing names constraints and slow down your queries because they have the same name

maybe this results helpful

> CREATE ONLY ONE CONSTRAINT INDEX AND INCLUDE THOSE NECESSARY COLUMNS

Example

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT findUser UNIQUE (nameUser,emailUser);
```

No double constraint and no warning message and you keep the SQL rules alive

> Remember SQL is an standard but not implemented at the same time for
>   everyone with the same rules

As you can see at the following link, in fact these scenario is a bug

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37520

and finally recognized in: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8565

and finally fixed in MySQL Server 5.6.7

Comment: He's using MySQL 5.7 (which is post-patch). On the contrary, he's getting the error message and complaining about it. The is no bug, he's suppose to get that message. There was a bug when there was no message.

Answer (score 0):

> When I tried the same in Postgres(10.x), it didn't warn me.

This simply isn't true.

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( a int );
ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT uk1 UNIQUE (a);
ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT uk1 UNIQUE (a);
ERROR:  relation "uk1" already exists
```

However, in PostgreSQL most people don't name anything because the system is awesome and the auto-generated names work fine,

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD UNIQUE (a); -- run once
ALTER TABLE foo ADD UNIQUE (a); -- run twice (no problem)

-- run thirce, and four times
ALTER TABLE foo ADD UNIQUE (a), ADD UNIQUE (a);
```

> So, what would the SQL standard be in this scenario?

This is called a `<table constraint definition>` in the spec, which says this (SQL:2011n).

> 4) Let *S* be the schema identified by the explicit or implicit  of the `<constraint name>`. *S* shall not include a constraint descriptor whose constraint name is `<constraint name>`.

Duplicate constraints are not permitted *for the entire schema*. As an aside, the spec also states the implementation can not generate implicit names that conflict (must be unique).

Comment: ,as It is clear that there are SQL standards on avoiding duplicate constraint names. So, the constraint (constraint created on same column, uk1(col1),uk2(col1)...)can be created 'N' times with unique names for each.